# Trying to set RadTreeView node checked status programatically from persistence

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radtreeview

There must be something I'm missing here. I have two instances of RadTreeView, for which I store node check data in a cookie. Upon page load, I then want to read this cookie, and set checked status accordingly.

So I have this OnDataBound event:

```
protected void RadTreeView1_OnDataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            HttpCookie checkedCookie = Request.Cookies[DataType + "Checked"];
            if (checkedCookie != null)
            {
                var cookieValue = checkedCookie.Values["Checked"];
                if (cookieValue != null)
                {
                    var checkedNodeValues = cookieValue.Split('*');
                    foreach (string nodeValue in checkedNodeValues)
                    {
                        RadTreeNode checkedNode = RadTreeView1.FindNodeByValue(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(nodeValue));
                        if (checkedNode != null)
                            checkedNode.Checked = true;
                    }
                }
            }                 
        }
```

And in the foreach loop, I find a corresponding node for every cookie value. What's more is, their initial Checked status is false.

So why are all *other* nodes also getting checked?

Comment: Do you have the CheckChildNodes = True? 

What about TriStateCheckBoxes?

Comment: CheckChildNodes = True. I am not using TriStateCheckBoxes.

Comment: That could explain why "other" nodes are also getting checked - because when CheckChildNodes is True and you check a parent - then all of its children get checked too.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the RadPersistenceFramework. Adding a single entry for your treeview to the PersistenceManager (or PersistenceManagerProxy) control should let you store the checked state. You can see this here http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/treeview/examples/applicationscenarios/persisting-treeview-settings/defaultcs.aspx?product=persistenceframework

Of course, storing the data depends a bit on your case (you can have a custom provider and still keep the data in a cookie, or you can keep things in a database, whatever works for you: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/persistence-framework/examples/custom-storage-provider/defaultcs.aspx).